# Trying to get 2 overlays to display in a picturebox in VB 2012

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to get 2 weather radar image overlays over top of each other in the Picturebox control. The dimensions of the graphics are both 600, 550. My code gives me no errors but when I run it, it just gives me a blank form. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
Dim Image1 As New Bitmap("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Overlays/Topo/Short/FWS_Topo_Short.jpg")
    Dim Image2 As New Bitmap("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/FWS_N0R_0.gif")
    Dim Image3 As New Bitmap(600, 550)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image3)
    g.DrawImage(Image1, New Point(0, 0))
    g.DrawImage(Image2, New Point(0, 0))
    PictureBox1.Image = Image3
    g.Dispose()
    g = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use URI for the Bitmap, you need to specify a local path. You can however use a stream with Bitmap so first open a stream to the site's image and load it in via that.

For example:

```
        Dim Image1 As Bitmap = GetStreamBitmap("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/Overlays/Topo/Short/FWS_Topo_Short.jpg")
        Dim Image2 As Bitmap = GetStreamBitmap("http://radar.weather.gov/ridge/RadarImg/N0R/FWS_N0R_0.gif")

        'TODO implement error checking, "if image1 is nothing" etc..

        Dim Image3 As New Bitmap(600, 550)
        Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image3)
        g.DrawImage(Image1, New Point(0, 0))
        g.DrawImage(Image2, New Point(0, 0))

        PictureBox1.Image = Image3

        g.Dispose()
        g = Nothing

        Image2.Dispose()
        Image1.Dispose()

'...

    Private Function GetStreamBitmap(url As String) As Bitmap

        Dim bmp As Bitmap = Nothing

        Try
            Dim request As System.Net.WebRequest = _
                System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url)

            Dim response As System.Net.WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
            Dim responseStream As System.IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            bmp = New Bitmap(responseStream)

        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
            ' handle error here
        End Try

        Return bmp

    End Function
```

Comment: Not directly related, or required, but for improved blending of the two images, add this directly after creating the Graphics object:         g.CompositingMode = Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceOver
        g.CompositingQuality = Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality